# ASP Web API Swagger - Ordering methods

Tags: swagger

I am using Swagger to document a ASP web API.

There is a logical order in which a user would call the methods. By default Swagger orders the methods alphabetically - Is anyone aware of a way of overriding the default ordering and specifying a custom order?

Thank you!

Comment: That highly depends on your programming language and on the swagger implementation.
Which Language are you using and which swagger and which swagger-ui Version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using C# & Swashbuckle 5.53 installed via NuGet.

Comment: Unfortunately I currently don't have the answer - if you would like to investigate yourself I would point you to https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/567.
Otherwise I'll mock up a API Project over the weekend and try to play with the OrderActionGroup.